# how to loop ndvi using R in sentinel-2

Tags: r, ndvi, loop, sentinel-2

I have a two different stacks: one for band 4 (RED) and other with band 8 (NIR).
I'm trying to loop the calculation of NDVI in an area of interest using R.

Well, this is the loop that I'm trying to use: First, I'm trying to crop the stacks using a shapefile, then calculate the NDVI of the area of interest and save this to the disk.

```
for(i in 1){

  b4_crop <- crop(stack_b4[i],AOI_Repro)

  b8_crop <- crop(stack_b8[i],AOI_Repro)

  ndvi <- (b4_crop[i]-b8_crop[i])/(b4_crop[i]-b8_crop[i])

  writeRaster(ndvi,output_name[i])

}
```

And this the message I get from it:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘crop’ for signature ‘"matrix"’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling with single brackets, use double. Raster stack is a kind of list:

Reproducible example (different sensor, same procedure)

```
library(raster)
library(RStoolbox)

data(lsat)

output_name <- paste0('raster',1:10,'.tif')

stack_b4 <-list()
stack_b8 <-list()

for(i in 1:10){
  stack_b4[[i]] <- lsat[[3]]
  stack_b8[[i]] <- lsat[[4]]
}

stack_b4 <- stack(stack_b4)
stack_b8 <- stack(stack_b8)

AOI_Repro <- as(extent(lsat,50,150,50,150),'SpatialPolygons')
```

For your procedure:

```
for (i in 1:length(stack_b4)) {

  b4_crop <- crop(stack_b4[[i]],AOI_Repro)

  b8_crop <- crop(stack_b8[[i]],AOI_Repro)

  ndvi <- (b4_crop-b8_crop)/(b4_crop-b8_crop)

  writeRaster(ndvi,output_name[i])

}
```

A better approach (IMO):

```
for (i in 1:length(stack_b4)) {

  b4_crop <- crop(stack_b4[[i]],AOI_Repro)

  b8_crop <- crop(stack_b8[[i]],AOI_Repro)

  ndvi <- overlay(x = b4_crop, y = b8_crop, fun = function(x,y) (y-x)/(y+x))

  writeRaster(ndvi,output_name[i])

}
```

A faster approach:

```
NDVI <- function(x,y){(y-x)/(y+x)}

beginCluster(12) # your availables cores

for (i in 1:length(stack_b4)) {

  b4_crop <- crop(stack_b4[[i]],AOI_Repro)

  b8_crop <- crop(stack_b8[[i]],AOI_Repro)

  ndvi <- clusterR(stack(b4_crop,b8_crop), calc, args = list(fun = NDVI))

  writeRaster(ndvi,output_name[i])

} 

endCluster()
```

Less lines:

```
stack_b4c <- crop(stack_b4, AOI_Repro)
stack_b8c <- crop(stack_b8, AOI_Repro)
mapply(FUN = function(x,filename) writeRaster(x, filename),x = mapply(function(x,y) (y-x)/(y+x), as.list(stack_b4c),  as.list(stack_b8c)), filename=as.list(output_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, what does this `for( i in 1)` loop do? i in 1 does not make any sense. Something like `for(i in 1:length(stack_b4))` would be more appropriate here.

Second, you need double brackets and since you are creating a new object of index i, you do not need to call the iterator again. You could, however, crop your stacks first and not do this within the for loop.

```
for(i in for(i in 1:length(stack_b4))){
  b4_crop <- crop(stack_b4[[i]],AOI_Repro)
  b8_crop <- crop(stack_b8[[i]],AOI_Repro)
  ndvi <- (b4_crop-b8_crop)/(b4_crop-b8_crop)
  writeRaster(ndvi, output_name[i])
}
```